# django nginx failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I get this permission error everytime I try to access media files

```
failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I have tried the solutions provided on the similar questions but they don't seem to be caused for the same reason.

Media folder permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu www-data   4096 Jun 26 21:55 media
```

This is also the same for the folder and file I'm trying to access.

I checked the nginx site config and everything seems to be okay and pointing at the same path but the problem is still there.

When I try to run the command

```
sudo -u www-data ls /home/ubuntu/library/media/
```

it says

```
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/library/media/': Permission denied
```

I'm new to nginx and ubuntu so I don't know what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: One user tries to access other user home directory. Try moving `media` elsewhere (/var/opt/ and so on) or check this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248286/home-users-permissions-denied

Comment: My user is ubuntu, it is the user that has the home directory.
While the nginx user is www-data. What exactly should I do?

Comment: Give permissions to `www-data` on `home/ubuntu` folder which is parent of `media` folder. Or keep your media files in some other folder, not in anybodies `home` folder, for example in `/var/opt/myproject/media`.